# How to add armadillo library to autotools project

Tags: autotools, armadillo

I want to add armadillo C++ linear algebra library to my autotools project. I am new to autotools and tried `PKG_CHECK_MODULE`, but had no chance. Any one can show me a simple example to add to `configure.ac` and `Makefile.am`.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem myself. Armadillo is a C++ template library and therefor there is no need to add it to `autotools` project :).